# What is the substitue for Tweet interface in java

Tags: java, twitter, interface, twitter4j

I have implemented the Tweet interface using the 2X version. But as of new API 3X in twitter4j It is not supporting the older Tweet interface as it was depracated. So What is the new way to use the Tweet interface or any other substitute is there

Comment: [TweetEntity](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TweetEntity.html)? Just a wild guess ...

Comment: Got the interface it is Status